Remove access to shared calendars / Delete calendars to a specific user
I was unable to find how to remove or delete a calendar for a user in my workspace.
I think I understand how to determine which calendars are shared with a specific user, with the help of this thread: Get list of shared calendars through Google Calendar API
So let's assume this is really the only way to identify which calendars are shared with other users.

I couldn't find a way how to delete these calendars for another user.
I couldn't find a way to get shared calendar between 2 users in my workspace (only calendars that I shared with users).
Same problem goes for cancel all future events for a user in my workspace.
If the user in my workspace created meeting in his own calendar, I can cancel them with this API.

Here is what I tried (that didn't work):

Get all calendars: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList

For each calendar that is not marked as primary, I call with get calendar ACL: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/acl


Which there I can see my shared user:
}
 "kind": "calendar#aclRule",
 "etag": "\"005555555500\"",
 "id": "user:jon@fakeDomain.com",
 "scope": {
      "type": "user",
      "value": "foo@fakeDomain.com"
  },
 "role": "reader"
}


Then I try to delete him with the API:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/acl/ruleId

Link to doc: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl/delete
The API returns success, but the user is still shared with the calendar.

What could be done differently?
How can I get all shared calendars for a user in my workspace?
How can I get all calendars events of a user in my workspace?

Any help would be much appreciated!
